# Boost C++: how to return file from folder via tcp?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, boost, tcp

so I have a folder "Assets" which is in the same folder with my server executable. I want to return file from it (ofcource if file exists) to any user that connects to my server via tcp and sends a filename (generally I wish to see a asinc, nonblocking tcp server made using boost which would simply return any file form folder near to the executable). How to do such thuing with boost?  (I use VS 2010 for compiling)

Comment: If you don't know how to do any of that with boost then how in the hell did you pick boost as your solution?

Comment: http://forum.try-catch.ru/index.php?topic=351.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a job for a web server. This is what web servers *do*. They are good at it.

Consider using one of the zillion web server apps out there or integrate a little web server into your program:
 - https://github.com/cloudmeter/pion

There are more linked from this question:
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175507/c-c-web-server-library